# OCR: check if letter is in (string) of image (Opencv, Python, Tesseract)

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract

This is a really tricky question.

I am using the following code to detect text in hand-written images. I don't want it to recognize the char, in this case it only create a bounding box around each character/word he find.

[image: o1]

This is the code:

```
import cv2
import tesserocr as tr
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('1.png')

idx = 0

# since tesserocr accepts PIL images, converting opencv image to pil
pil_img = Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))

# initialize api
api = tr.PyTessBaseAPI()

alphabet_min = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
                'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

alphabet_max = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M',
                'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

try:
    api.SetImage(pil_img)
    boxes = api.GetComponentImages(tr.RIL.SYMBOL, True)
    text = api.GetUTF8Text()
    print(text)

    for (im, box, _, _) in boxes:
        x, y, w, h = box['x'], box['y'], box['w'], box['h']
        #print(box)

        #if w < 200:
            #cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=1)

    for letter in text:
        if letter in alphabet_min:
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=-1)

    idx += 1

finally:
    api.End()

cv2.imshow('2', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

If you take a closer look, you can see a `print(text)`. This one print the text he find in the image. But, being this a hand-made text, it recovers near nothing:

```
Ca) a1 1. s 5305 Fm“. 4 54 0235 166 ﬁrm 4 §24630455
```

But even this output can help me in some way.

A little above in the code, I made a function:

```
for letter in text:
        if letter in alphabet_min:
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=-1)
```

This *should* take every char in the `print(text)` output and compare it to the `alphabet_min` list in the code.
But it don't wanna work. I don't know why ?

The purpose of this is: if you find a letter in `print(text)` and this is equal to one of `alphabet_min` list, then cover it in the image (using `cv2.rectangle`) using its correspondent in the image.

Any suggestion ?

Source image is this:

[image: src]

**EDIT**

Doing a print(True) under the condition, it show `6 True`. This means it finds the letter. The only problem is it don't create the bounding box for them..

Comment: `x, y, w, h` are set to the values for the last box by the first `for`-loop. Other boxes are not processed.

Comment: So what should I do ? Create another for ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it...

So, this is the new code:

```
import cv2
import tesserocr as tr
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('1.png')

idx = 0

# since tesserocr accepts PIL images, converting opencv image to pil
pil_img = Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))

# initialize api
api = tr.PyTessBaseAPI()

alphabet_min = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
                'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

alphabet_max = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M',
                'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

t = 0
try:
    api.SetImage(pil_img)
    boxes = api.GetComponentImages(tr.RIL.SYMBOL, True)
    text = api.GetUTF8Text()

    for (im, box, _, _) in boxes:
        x, y, w, h = box['x'], box['y'], box['w'], box['h']
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=1)

        print(text[t])

        for letter in alphabet_min:
            if text[t] in letter:
                cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=-1)

        t += 1
        cv2.imshow('2', img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)


    idx += 1


finally:
    api.End()
```

Comment: you should remove the line 
####for letter in alphabet_min:

Comment: I found this really helpful